# How do I give this popup a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure this out for the life of me. On this page, if the browser height is too small, you won't be able to see the full form. How do I add a scroll bar to the popup so that people with small screen sizes will still be able to see the entire form from top to bottom?

http://kinkarso.com/rayku/profile.html

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the CSS `overflow` property.

Comment: Here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/RxKxw/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change `position: fixed;` to `position: relative;` (*or `absolute` if you want it to be overlaid something else*) on the `.filter-popup` class

Comment: He wants to position his popup, so it has to be position: absolute

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the CSS `position` attribute for your popup (using `filter_popup` class). If you used `position: fixed`, the containing element will not grow to accommodate it. Change it to `position: absolute` instead and the scroll bar will appear.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you should use `overflow:scroll` which is the css way of creating scroll bars.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp